# Equalizing indexes of Pandas Series to fit into Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe that uses a datetime index. I want to add a column onto the dataframe that returns an average of a particular slice of the data. This column does not always include the entire index, I need a way to fill in the missing portions with zeros.

Dataframe:
`[2020-7-26 | 29.3]   [2020-8-02 | 28.2]   [2020-8-09 | 26.7]   [2020-8-16 | 24.1]   [2020-8-30 | 23.2]`

Series I wish to append: Note the missing august 16th
`[2020-7-26 | 20.3]   [2020-8-02 | 21.2]   [2020-8-09 | 23.7]   [2020-8-30 | 22.2]`

Is there a way to transform this series into:
`[2020-7-26 | 20.3]   [2020-8-02 | 21.2]   [2020-8-09 | 23.7]   [2020-8-16 | 0.0]   [2020-8-30 | 22.2]` 
In order to be able to form this Dataframe:
`[2020-7-26 | 29.3 | 20.3]   [2020-8-02 | 28.2 | 21.2] [2020-8-09 | 26.7 | 23.7]   [2020-8-16 | 24.1 | 0.0]   [2020-8-30 | 23.2 | 22.2]`  
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you simply want to join the two together on their datetime index. Let `df` be your dataframe with more indices and `ser` be your series with missing indices.

if `df` is:

```
           val
date    
2019-08-01  1
2019-08-02  2
2019-08-03  3
```

and `ser` is:

```
date
2019-08-01    4
2019-08-03    5
```

It should be simply:

```
df.join(ser,how='left').fillna(0)
```

which yields:

```
           val  val2
date        
2019-08-01  1   4.0
2019-08-02  2   0.0
2019-08-03  3   5.0
```

as the left join would fill any missing on the right with `nans`, which `fillna()` would impute with 0.

Make sure your series has a name however otherwise the join doesn't know how to name your new column. You can do so by setting
`ser.name = 'column_name'` before you call join, which in my case here is `'val2'`.

Also if you don't understand why I'm calling `how='left'` I would recommend you take some time to read into what left,right,outer,inner joins are as it is quite essential to not just preprocessing in python but sql as well. Good luck!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Left outer join totally slipped my mind thanks for the refresher!